# Web technique to resize an image over a given time interval

Tags: javascript, image, html

Is there a technique to resize an image over a given time interval?

What I want to do is have an image and when the mouse rolls overs it, it should resize the image making it larger.  All I can find are simple rollover scripts that instantly resize the image.  I want to do it over a period of about a second.

And as a must it cannot lag and destroy the visual experience.  I am looking for an approach in javascript, jQuery, or HTML5 if it's possible; other suggestions appreciated but no flash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very easy with CSS3 Transitions:

```
.myImg
{
    width: 200px;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
}
.myImg:hover
{
    width: 300px;
}
```

**Demo:** [jsfiddle.net/yyDd4](http://jsfiddle.net/yyDd4/)

Comment: Perfect.  +1 for including the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in jQuery in this way.

```
var factor = 2;

$('#foo').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        top: '-=' + $(this).height() / factor,
        left: '-=' + $(this).width() / factor,
        width: $(this).width() * factor
    });
});
```

and the other techniques are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870655/image-resizing-with-jquery-animate).

Comment: Is it possible to specify a period of time that the animation should occur over?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in plain javascript, though animation is always surprisingly complicated, especially if you want the image to shrink back after the mouse moves off it. Making an object to store the state is possibly the best solution and is also quite adaptable (other images, other types of animation).

http://jsfiddle.net/VceD9/6/

```
new GrowingImage('myImage', 2, 1000);

function GrowingImage(id, factor, duration) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id),
        originalWidth = el.offsetWidth,
        originalHeight = el.offsetHeight,
        timer, 
        stage = 0,
        frameRate = 17,
        maxStage = duration / frameRate;
    el.onmouseover = function () {
        animate(1);
    };
    el.onmouseout = function () {
        animate(-1);
    };
    function animate(direction) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            stage += direction;
            if (stage <= 0) {
                stage = 0;
                clearInterval(timer);
            } else if (stage >= maxStage) {
                stage = maxStage;
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
            var scale = 1 + (factor - 1) * stage / maxStage;
            el.style.width = originalWidth * scale + 'px';
            el.style.height = originalHeight * scale + 'px';
        }, frameRate);
    }
}
```

If *exact* timing is important to you, you may need to adjust this so that it keeps track of the amount of time that the current animation has been running.