# Increase/decrease size of image without changing layout

Tags: jquery, html, css

I found this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xhchp/3/)  in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870655/image-resizing-with-jquery-animate) which I think works great for me.

However unlike the example I do not want to clone the image just change the image position and size.

How should I rewrite the code to make this possible?

Here is the code:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
function ZoomIn(){
    var p = $(this).offset();
    var w = $(this).width();
    var h = $(this).height();
    var $clone = $(this).clone();
    $clone.css({
        position: "absolute",
        left: p.left + "px",
        top: p.top + "px",
        "z-index": 2
    }).appendTo('body');
    $clone.data("origWidth",w);
    $clone.data("origHeight",h);
    $clone.data("origTop",p.top);
    $clone.data("origLeft",p.left);
    $clone.animate({
        top: "-=" + Math.floor(h * 0.5),
        left: "-=" + Math.floor(w * 0.5),
        width: Math.floor(w * 2),
        height: Math.floor(h * 2)
    },function(){
    });
    $clone.click(ZoomOut);
}

function ZoomOut(){
    var w = $(this).data("origWidth");
    var h = $(this).data("origHeight");
    var t = $(this).data("origTop");
    var l = $(this).data("origLeft");
    $(this).animate({
        top: t,
        left: l,
        width: w,
        height: h
    },function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
}

$(function(){
    $('img').click(ZoomIn);
});
});//]]>  

</script>
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea it's possible, see edited **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e0g8kp32/6/)**

- I've removed the clone method and added changing of events - calling methods ZoomIn/ZoomOut

the code is:

```
function ZoomIn() {
    var p = $(this).offset();
    var w = $(this).width();
    var h = $(this).height();
    var $self = $(this);

    $self.data("origWidth", w);
    $self.data("origHeight", h);
    $self.data("origTop", p.top);
    $self.data("origLeft", p.left);
    $self.animate({
        top: "-=" + Math.floor(h * 0.5),
        left: "-=" + Math.floor(w * 0.5),
        width: Math.floor(w * 2),
        height: Math.floor(h * 2)
    }, function () {
        $self.off("click");
        $self.click(ZoomOut);
    });     
}

function ZoomOut() {
    var w = $(this).data("origWidth");
    var h = $(this).data("origHeight");
    var t = $(this).data("origTop");
    var l = $(this).data("origLeft");
    $(this).animate({
        top: t,
        left: l,
        width: w,
        height: h
    }, function () {
        $(this).off("click");
        $(this).click(ZoomIn);
    });

}

$(function () {
    $('img').click(ZoomIn);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this code


<div style="float:left">
    <img id="someImage" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/16/Deletion_icon.svg/600px-Deletion_icon.svg.png"/>
    <div>
<div>
<p>Some random text.</p>
<p>More blah.  More blah.</p>
<p>Some random text.</p>
</div>
```